# Group by in json object

Tags: postgresql

I have table

```
SELECT client_number, jsonsample FROM testjson;
```

table data:

| client_number | jsonsample |
| --- | --- |
| "1221" | "{""StatementType"": [2, 3]}" |
| "1221" | "{""StatementType"": ["CO", "AB"]}" |
| "2332" | "{""StatementType"": ["CO", "CD"]}" |

need to know all the client number which has jsonsample as CO using group by

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON path query to get the results you want. This only works on `jsonb` not `json`, so you need to cast if necessary

```
SELECT *
FROM testjson tj
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(tj.jsonsample::jsonb, '$.StatementType[*] ? (@ == "CO")')
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c6cb4cad9a64b0699b37020a057d0562)

- `$.StatementType` retrieves that property, which is an array
- `[*]` retrieves all array values
- `?` begins a filter...
- ...where `(@ == "CO")` the value is `CO`